# Remove lines between quad glyphs in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to create a 2D histogram with square bins (instead of hex elements) and I'm using quad to do so.

First, I create a 2D histogram using numpy (not shown for brevity).

Then I plot it using the quad glyph:

```
    def plotHist2D(self,name):
        """
        Creates a 2D histogram figure in Bokeh.

        Parameters
        ----------
        name : string
            The name of one of the column data sources in self.files.

        Returns
        -------
        A bokeh plot object.
        """
        cds = ColumnDataSource(self.makeHist2D(name))
        plot_cmap = linear_cmap('tops','Turbo256',0,1,)
        bar_cmap = LinearColorMapper(palette='Turbo256',low=0,high=1)
        p = figure(plot_height=350,plot_width=350,
                   title='kW/mm^2',                                                                                                     x_axis_label='x (m)',
                   y_axis_label='y (m)',
                   x_range=(-0.05,0.05),
                   y_range=(-0.05,0.05),
                   output_backend="webgl",
                   toolbar_location="above")
        p.quad(top='yrights',bottom='ylefts',left='xlefts',right='xrights',
               fill_color=plot_cmap,line_color=plot_cmap,
               line_width=0.1,line_alpha=1.0,
               alpha=1.0,source=cds)
        color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=bar_cmap,width=8,
                             border_line_color=None,location=(0,0))
        p.add_layout(color_bar,'right')
        return p
```

This functions, in that it creates a figure, but the figure has unpleasant lines at the border between the quad elements.

[image: Quad histogram]

I cannot find any combination of settings for the parameters line_width, line_color, and line_alpha that will get rid of these lines.  Is there any combination of settings that will eliminate those lines entirely?

If not, how should I be creating this 2D histogram with square bins?

Comment: Remove `line_width` and `line_alpha` arguments. If that doesn't work, please provide a minimal reproducible example, including the data that can be used to reproduce the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick to this is to use `line_color` with the same color mapper and not set `line_width` too small.

The following call to quad works.

```
p.quad(top='yrights',bottom='ylefts',left='xlefts',right='xrights',
               fill_color=plot_cmap,
               line_color=plot_cmap,
               line_width=1.0,line_alpha=1.0,
               alpha=1.0,source=cds)
```

The desired plot:

[image: Desired plot]

I thought I had tried every permutation before asking this question.  I'm not sure why a smaller `line_width` makes the lines more visible.  As @EugenePakhomov suggests you can also just leave out the `line_width` entirely.  Presumably this is because the default setting is large enough not to cause the "meshing."